# Wiring new ceiling fan to existing light switch box

Tags: wiring, lighting

I will be installing a ceiling fan/light kit in our bedroom that did not have any sort of ceiling fixture before.  Currently, the only light switch in the room is a two-way switch that controls the top half of a wall outlet (the jumper tab is broken off on the outlet).

My plan was to install a double-gang box in the wall where the current light switch is and run the new 14/2 cable through the attic to the new fan.  When I took out the existing light switch i noticed this configuration, where the white wire is always hot and the black is switched hot:

[image]

Then within the box is the following:

[image]

I know it may be tough to make out but one set of nutted wire are two white wires coming out of the wall.  The second set are three wires, the black and white coming from the switch and a red line wire coming from the wall.

My question is, if I want to add a second light switch for independent control of a new ceiling fan, how do I tie that into the current wiring configuration?

Comment: For starters, be sure to run 14/3, not 14/2.

Comment: Why 3-way? So the second switch can draw power from the first?

Comment: You said, "...run the new 14/2 cable through the attic to the new fan". You'll need two hot legs to independently control the light and the fan. Use 14/3.

Comment: And someone will be along shortly to diagram it for you. We have a couple good sketchers on board. Looks like there's everything you need in that switch box.

Comment: I bought the 14/2 because I'm OK with having the one switch turn on/off both the light and the fan and then pull the chain on the fan itself to turn on/off the light and/or the fan.  Or am I not thinking about that correctly?

Comment: Even if you want both on one switch for now, a spare power wire, capped off, is cheap insurance against a change of mind or a new device in the future. The difference between 14/2 and 14/3 is pretty small on a single run.

Comment: Yeah, you want the 14/3 so you can put a speed switch in for the fan and control the power and speed of the fan seperately from the light. If you are running wire anyway, the cost is minimal compared to the convenience of controlling each of them separately from the switch location.

Comment: Thanks guys this is very informative and helpful.  But just so I understand fully, basically you're saying that it makes sense to run 14/3, but I can still make it work properly (albeit potentially less convenient in the long run) with 14/2?

Comment: Yes. The requirements are the same.

Comment: Because 14/3 would allow me to have a switch (lets say thats push button but also has a dimmer) to have one control the light and the other to control the fan, whereas 14/2 my only option is to have the switch control both the light and the fan at the same time.  And the only way to have the fan stay on and the light turn off is to pull the chain on the fan itself...?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have one switch operate light OR fan. Many jurisdictions absolutely require that a switch on the wall near a room entrance, control a **lamp.** That is to benefit house guests and mainly from the government's perspective, first responders. There's an exception to allow a switched outlet instead, presuming a person is going to plug a floor lamp into that.  There is no exception to allow a fan/light locally switched at the fan. (such things can exist, they can't be the only light). That said:

They now make gadgets to solve the "I have 14/2 and wish I had 14/3" problem.  Each has a smart switch (typically 1-gang) with 2 controls, and a control module which sits under the fan shroud.   The switch communicates with the module either via powerline networking or via wireless, and some of those are compatible with smartphones or integrated home-automation systems as are now emerging in the market.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the switch, the connected white wire is the hot wire.(They should have marked it black for identification). It taps to the "red" wire which goes to the "hot terminal" of the receptacle. And of course the black wire on the switch controls the "switched half" of the receptacle. On the NEW switch to the fan, connect a jumper wire from the white "hot" of the old switch to the bottom terminal of the new switch. And the 14/2 feeding the fan, the black wire on the top terminal is the switch leg to the fan. The remaining white wire to the fan is the neutral conductor and it taps to the neutral "return" inside the box.Hopes this helps.